# How to generate lined paper with 52 degree slant dotted line

Tags: paper

I've seen numerous questions answered for generating lined paper.
I want to add a 52 degree slanted dotted line for cursive practice.
Is there any package that can help?
Line height should be 5mm and slanted line should be 52 degrees.

[image: sample document]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need Ti*k*Z. This code draws the grid in one page only, but you can use some packages to draw the grid on every page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\y 
\path (current page.south west);
\pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
\foreach \i in {0cm,.5cm,1cm,1.5cm,...,30cm} % Let's draw it to the outside of the paper - 
                                             % who cares?  
    \draw[dotted] (\x,\y+\i) -- ++ (22,0);
\foreach \i in {-30cm,-29.5cm,...,30cm}
    \draw[dotted] (\x,\y+\i) -- ++ (52:35);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```